# How to trigger Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey userscript in Slack web verision?

Tags: slack, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm having trouble getting any userscript to execute in Slack web interface.
The script is loaded with the page, as shown by Tampermonkey, but it doesn't even write into the console.

Even something totally basic like below has no effect.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    Namespace
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://app.slack.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    console.log('==================');
})();
```

I tried to use waitForKeyElements but with no success.
Is there a way around this?

**EDIT:**
It appears to be a problem specifically with Firefox (101.0 (64-bit)) & Tampermonkey 4.17.6161, as Edge (Version 102.0.1245.33 (Official build) (64-bit)) & Tampermonkey 4.16.1 works fine with the same userscript.

Comment: Show us your full userscript... sounds like a problem with the @match line - TM script is not being triggered by the URL

Comment: There is nothing fancy there, but I updated the post. Did some more testing and it seems it's either browser, Tampermonkey, or some browser config issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so letting you know that it worked for me.  But there were many other lines that flooded the console (especially in a Slack channel), so I made sure the console log I added would be easy to notice. Here's what I added:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         ___NewUserscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @match        https://app.slack.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
console.log('**********************************************************************');
console.log('**********************************************************************');
console.log('**********************************************************************');
console.log('**********************************************************************');
console.log('**********************************************************************');
console.log('**********************************************************************');
console.log('**********************************************************************');
console.log('**********************************************************************');
console.log('**********************************************************************');
console.log('**********************************************************************');
})();
```

In the console, my blocks of asterisks were added about 15 lines down, and then scads of lines appeared after that.

You are probably right that it's a Firefox problem - I tried my script with Brave browser (a secure variant of Chrome by the same guy who created Firefox) and it worked fine.

If that's the answer (i.e. Firefox vs Chrome/Edge), please add that as an answer and mark it as the correct answer in order to close out the question and make it easy for the next guy.

Comment: Browsers have a filter on the output, so it's easy to tell it to ignore all logs except a unique string, for example, `cssyphus`. And that isn't showing up on FF 117.0.1 for me, on Slack only (yes, the [1] indicator shows so the script is supposed to be running).

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a problem specifically with Firefox (101.0 (64-bit)) & Tampermonkey 4.17.6161, as Edge (Version 102.0.1245.33 (Official build) (64-bit)) & Tampermonkey 4.16.1 works fine with the same userscript.
There are few variables here, but I consider this an answer to this question sufficient to my current needs.